# Does part of video exist in other video

Tags: video

Lets say you have 1000 video files, with different length

- Some are clips from other videos
- Some are worse quality than other videos
- Some are compilations of other videos
- Some have same video, but different sound

The goal is to get rid of all duplicates with worst quality and shortest length.

It cant use video thumbnail or file name, since they share thumbnail from the websites they came from, and the titles are just random generated like "website.com_2485629876a0fbf2cb55670958ee2ea2-1.mp4".

Does any software exist that can do this?

Comment: you could train a neural network to aid in this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual technique to detect whether a video matches another is called Video Finger printing.

It is often used to detect copywriter infringements and pirated videos.

There is at lest one open source video fingerprinting project ava

- http://www.phash.org

For your case where it sounds like you need to identify clips you will probably have to also come up with an efficient way to break down the videos into the parts you want to try to match.